# Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 Ruby facter

Tags: ruby, utf-8, facter

I'm trying to write a fact for Puppet.

I have an array with usernames `array = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]` and then a code

```
array.each do |item|
    temp_data << Facter::Core::Execution.exec("net user #{item} /DOMAIN")
end
search_text = %r{comment|Local}
users_data = []
temp_data.each do |line|
    line.each_line do |num|
    users_data << (num) unless num =~ search_text
    end
end
```

temp_data generates fine, but I get an error **ERROR puppetlabs.facter - error while resolving custom fact "winusers_domain": invalid byte sequence in UTF-8** but it doesn't show witch line the error is. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out so I answer to myself.

```
array.each do |item|
    temp_data << Facter::Core::Execution.exec("net user #{item} /DOMAIN")
end
search_text = %r{comment|Local}
users_data = []
temp_data.each do |line|
    line.encode!('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :replace => '')
    line.encode!('UTF-8', 'UTF-16')
    line.each_line do |num|
    users_data << (num) unless num =~ search_text
    end
end
```